# gRpc transcoding is not working- unable to find annotation.proto and http.proto are thrown

Tags: .net-7.0, grpc-dotnet

I'm trying to do gRpc Transcoding with .NET 7. I'm following the article [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/json-transcoding?view=aspnetcore-7.0). I'm also referring to the sample implementation [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/master/examples/Transcoder). After I added the proto files annotation.proto and http.proto and include the annotations.proto to the main proto file. I get the error

> Rebuild started...
>
> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: CacheService, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>
> Restored C:\CarryCase\Venkatesh\M2c\grpc\net7\CacheService\CacheService.csproj (in 40 ms).
>
> 1>google/api/annotations.proto : error : File not found.
>
> 1>Protos/cache.proto(2,1): error : Import "google/api/annotations.proto" was not found or had errors.
>
> 1>Done building project "CacheService.csproj" -- FAILED.
>
> ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>
> ========== Elapsed 00:00.428 ==========

The code for the same is available at [here (grpc-transcoding)](https://github.com/VenkateshSrini/GRpcFileCache/tree/gRpc-transcoding)

I tried to create a gRPC transcoding code with .NET 7. But the proto definitions are not getting properly included resulting in error. I would expect it to work as told in reference articles

Comment: Did you follow "Usage" step 3 in that article?  `Add google/api/http.proto and google/api/annotations.proto files to the project.`

Comment: Yes I have done that. You can see the code in the above link

Comment: The error complains very directly about not being able to find the file.  Maybe you need to pass a path to the `protoc` binary to point to it (`-I`, possibly).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. I had worked with grpc-dotnet team. Detailed solutions is at (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/1965). My proto files are in folder structure
[image]

With this structure in `cache.protos` we need to use `Protos/google/api/annotations.proto` and in `annotations.proto` we need to use `Protos/google/api/http.proto`. Also there was a message `CustomHttpPattern` missing that I added from the appropriate repo. The completed solution is available on my public github repo https://github.com/VenkateshSrini/GRpcFileCache/tree/gRpc-transcoding